# How to fetch the content from the PDF into a string using QTP/VBScript?

Tags: validation, vbscript, qtp

I need to validate a particular content from the PDF using **QTP**. How I can get the content from the PDF into the string Using **QTP/VBScript.** So that, I can validate the content in the PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do visit [Here](http://www.learnqtp.com/learnquicktestpdf-api-manipulating-pdfs-in-qtp/). You will get your answer, this is one of the menthod to work with PDF in QTP. You can also fetch data from PDF by passing Keys i,e, Ctrl+a then Ctrl+c then copy this data to Clipboard & use this data for comparing with your standard data

Sample Function For Getting data from PDF, When PDF report is open in Broweser whose creation time is passed in datatable

```
Public function CopyPDFData(sDestinationFile)       
Dim clip, strText, nCT, fso

nCT = DataTable("bPDFCreationTime", dtLocalSheet)
If nCT =""  Then nCT=1
Browser("CreationTime:=" & nCT).Sync

Browser("CreationTime:=" & nCT).FullScreen            
wait(2)
Browser("CreationTime:=" & nCT).WinObject("object class:=AVL_AVView", "text:=AVPageView").Type micCtrlDwn + "a" + micCtrlUp
wait(4)
Browser("CreationTime:=" & nCT).WinObject("object class:=AVL_AVView", "text:=AVPageView").Type micCtrlDwn + "c" + micCtrlUp
wait(4)

Set clip = CreateObject("Mercury.Clipboard" )
strText = clip.GetText
clip.Clear

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set strfile = fso.CreateTextFile(sDestinationFile, True) 
strfile .Write  strText
strfile .Close
Browser("CreationTime:=" & nCT).sync
Browser("CreationTime:=" & nCT).close
End Function
```

Let me know if this solves your problem, there are also other alternatives for PDF Report testing using QTP