# Getting an error while using the function of a loaded assembly(dll)

Tags: .net, qtp

I have created an assembly(dll) in C#.net. It is for reading PDF files, so I have use "itextsharp" assembly as reference assembly in dll.
Now loading the assembly using dotnetfactory feature, I tried to use a function for reading the pdf file. I am getting following error.

> External object PdfToText.PdfClass::ReadPdfFile has thrown the following exception:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

Where PdfToText is namespace name used in dll and PdfClass is class name.Function name is "ReadPdfFile".

```
Set obj = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("PdfToText.PdfClass","C:\myassembly.dll")
str=obj.ReadPdfFile("C:myfile.pdf")
```

Comment: Do you want content from PDF into string?

Comment: yes I want to read pdf in QTP and try to do that thing in .net and use the dll created in .net in QTP But it throws an error.

Comment: Please Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323464/how-to-fetch-the-content-from-the-pdf-into-a-string-using-qtp-vbscript/
Also let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: The solution given by you is really a good one.I really appreciate.But in your solution preconditionis "When PDF report is open in Broweser whose creation time is passed in datatable".But in my case I have only the path of the PDF file, rest I need to tackle.And the LearnQTP one,yes it solves my work not my query.I want to do in the same scenario as they have done.

Comment: You noticed the fact that you missed a \ in `C:myfile.pdf`?

Comment: You can open the file by invoking `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore "C:\myfile.pdf"`, it will open the file in internet explorer, then you can use the method 4M01 mentioned to capture it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  Missed the error

Just add the itextsharp assembly to your referenced assemblies and that should solve the problem.

Comment: I have itextsharp assembly added with referenced assemblies. But when I am trying to use the assembly in QTP then it throws the error.

Comment: Is the itextsharp assembly in the same folder as the dll you are loading or is it in the GAC?

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder.